# Command substitution with xargs inputs

Tags: shell-script, find, xargs, command-substitution, ln

I'm trying to write a simple command that will create symlinks for all files in a specific directory (Yes, exactly like `lndir` but I cannot use it so I try to mimic it).

I tried the following using `find` + `xargs`:

```bsh
find $(realpath ${FROM_DIR}) -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} ln -sfn {} ${TO_DIR}/$(basename {})
```

But the problem is that the shell substitutes  `$(basename {})` once before the line is executed, and not for every argument.

Writing it as a loop looks like this:

```bsh
for i in $(find $(realpath ${FROM_DIR}) -maxdepth 1)
do
    ln -sfn $i ${TO_DIR}/$(basename $i)
done
```

This works, but it is relatively slow.
I was wondering if this can be done using `xargs` as well.

Comment: Note the core of your issue, but you may want to read: [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
ln -sf -- "$(realpath -- "$FROM_DIR")"/* "$TO_DIR/"
```

When the last argument is a directory, `ln`, like `cp` or `mv` creates links to the other argument with same basename *inside* that directory.

Or with `zsh`:

```
ln -sf -- $FROM_DIR:P/* $TO_DIR/
```

Which would also behave better if the real path of `$FROM_DIR` cannot be determined or no file can be found in `$FROM_DIR`.

(add the `D` qualifier to also create symlinks for the hidden files).

Or if you really needed to call one `ln` invocation per file for some reason:

```
for f ($FROM_DIR:P/*(ND)) ln -sfT -- $f $TO_DIR/$f:t
```

(note that `-n` and `-T` are non-standard extensions).

To use shell command substitution with `xargs` (or here, with `find -exec`, using `xargs` would be pointless) you'd need them to run a shell:

```
TO_DIR=$TO_DIR find "$(realpath -- "$FROM_DIR")" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  -exec sh -c '
    for file do
      ln -sfn -- "$file" "$TO_DIR/$(basename -- "$file")"
    done' sh {} +
```

But bear in mind that `basename` can't be used in command substitution for arbitrary files as command substitution strips all trailing newline characters (there's the same problem with `$(realpath)` here). You'd better use `sh`'s `${file##*/}` or `zsh` `$file:t` here (`$FROM_DIR:P` for `realpath`).

Here, you only need:

```
find "$(realpath -- "$FROM_DIR")" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
  -exec ln -sft "$TO_DIR" -- {} +
```

though (`-t` being also a GNU extension). That one is not affected by the *too many arguments* errors you could get if there are too many files in `$TO_DIR` (in `zsh`, you'd work around it by using `zargs` or by loading the `zsh/files` module to get a builtin version of `ln`).

See also these Q&A's for other problems with your attempts:

- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)